# salesforce: packaging the app with custom profile

Tags: salesforce

I add custom profile in the package, however, I can't create the custom profile by installing. After more investigating, if I created the custom profile before the installation the package can update the fls and permissions. There is no way creating custom profile on installation? If so can I do that with installation script?

Comment: By the way you can ask your question about salesforce directly at http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2):

Took me a while to figure it out but here's the solution:

### IN YOUR DE ORG:

1. Clone Standard Platform User profile (because is the one that has the Salesforce Platform license) and name it something meaningful like MyApp_Profile
2. Customize MyApp_Profile to match your desired access level for the users that will test or use your app
3. Add custom profile settings MyApp_Profile to the package
4. Go ahead an finish the package

### IN THE TEST_ORG (OR YOUR_CUSTOMER_ORG):

1. Pre-create a profile by cloning the Standard Platform User profile and name it something meaningful like MyApp_TestProfile
2. Assign MyApp_TestProfile to a user
3. Install the package and on Step 2 (Choose security level) of  the wizard you have to select the third option (Select security settings)
4. Under "Customize security" section make sure the MyApp_TestProfile (created on step 5) has the MyApp_Profile assigned (created on step 1)
5. Finish the Package installation
6. Log to the test or customer org with the user that has the MyApp_TestProfile assigned and choose your App from top right menu.
7. You're welcome!

I hope this solves your issue too!